# Is this right usage of factory pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-pattern

Got design problem, maybe you can help to decide.

My client object can ask for set of objects of class `Report`. There is defined set of available reports and according to client's permissions different reports can included in returned set. Reports are created per request (every client gets brand new report instances on each request).

Should I use kind of "factory" that will encapsulate reports creation like below:

```
public class ReportsFactory {

    private UserPermissionsChecker permissionsChecker;

    public Set<Report> createReports() {
        Set<Report> reports = new HashSet<Report>();
        if(permissionsChecker.hasAccessTo('report A')) {
            reports.add(createReportA());
        }
        if(permissionsChecker.hasAccessTo('report B')) {
            reports.add(createReportB());
        }
        if(permissionsChecker.hasAccessTo('report C')) {
            reports.add(createReportC());
        }
        return reports;
    }

    private Report createReportA() {...}
    private Report createReportB() {...}
    private Report createReportC() {...}
}
```

Is this right usage of so called simple Factory pattern? Or do you have other suggestions?

** EDIT **

Some comments below say it's not exactly Factory pattern. If not, how could I call that?

Comment: I don't see any problem with this. Is there any specific reason why you are doubting your approach?

Comment: Those repeated "if" sections with the same pattern: if entitled then create. I was wondering if there is any better way to encapsulate it even more, e.g. follow "tell don't ask" principle. But I think it might be overengineering then.

Comment: those `if` are contained internally. No other code would have to be changed if you add support for more reports. So imho that's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the design is correct, but this is a wrong usage of the "Factory" word. In the Factory pattern, `XxxxFactory` creates instances of `Xxxx`, initializes them if required, but applies no other kind of logic.

This design here seems correct to me, but your class would rather be called `ReportsService`

And maybe `UserPermissionsChecker` would be `AuthorizationService`

**Edit:** To take into account criticism against the word "Service".

There is currently a quite widespread (I did not say universal) convention in the java world, which consists in having:

- A purely descriptive business-model implemented by classes emptied of all logic called (maybe mistakenly) POJOs
- All business logic mainly related to an object Xxx implemented in a procedural style in the methods of a class called XxxService.

**I personally don't agree with this coding style** and I prefer ***[object oriented programming](http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/object-oriented-programming)***, but whether we like it or not, this convention exists in the Java EE world and has it's coherence.

Judging bye the coding style of the class submitted by the OP, I inferred that he followed this procedural approach. In that situation, it's better to follow the existing convention and call the class that serves as a container for the procedural code which handles Reports a ReportService.

Comment: So to justify Factory usage I could encapsulate Set<Reports> into say AvailableReports and then I'd have AvailableReportsFactory? Am I right?

Comment: I'm not convinced that calling everything "Service" is much better. It's a very vague word, almost no better than "Manager" or "Object". It might be better to use words in the language of the domain. E.g. it's not the permissions checker that `hasAccessTo()` a report,  nor is it the AuthorizationService. It's a `User` that has the access. Perhaps the `User` should have that method on it instead?

Comment: That's a bit tricky as I need some kind of backend ekhm... "service" to fetch user permissions on every request. As user is simple pojo I have no ability to have access to this service. I could have method on user taking permission service as second param, but I guess it is even worse.

Comment: @aetheria Agreed, I edited my answer to take your point into account.

Comment: >*and I prefer object oriented programming* - The style you describe is still OOP. Do you in the normal world ask a cake to bake itself? See this reference for a more thorough explanation than can be put here: http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=61669#342766

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks a bit of a [builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) pattern, in a sense you have an object, that you build its data to. 
This is in contrast to a factory, where usually returns different concrete types of created objects, 
And usually the construction of the data of these objects is done in the CTORs of the concrete classes that objects of them are returned from the factory.